# Boost elasticsearch search based on entry field value

Tags: elasticsearch

I have 500M entries in an elasticsearch index. Each one belongs to one of 5000 different sources (entries have an integer attribute named "source").
Now, to do a search, I want to boost them by source: for each source id, I want to have a different boost.
Boosts can change over time (say, once per hour), so index-time boosting doesn't look like a good idea.

So, how do I do it?

I googled this, but haven't found anything really useful.
I put two possible options that I found in an answer, but maybe I have a better option?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to transform each class into a parent as children entries -- but then all children (entries) for a source will be put into the same shard (and entries are very unevenly distributed between sources), and that I'll need to change the DB schema, rebuild the database and update all existing code.

Another option is to put every source into a different index, and use index_boost. With the same downsides, and also then I'll need to provide the boosts in the query (would have worked if I only had 5 sources).